# Using Autosuggest API by mapmyindia

Tags: javascript, web-applications, autosuggest, mapmyindia-api

I'm sort of getting started with web-dev. I'm trying to build a web-app in which I'm trying to use the autosuggest API by [mapmyindia](https://www.mapmyindia.com/api/advanced-maps/doc/interactive-map-api). I signed up and got the API key as well as authentication token. Now i can't figure out how to use the autosuggest API by reading the [documentation](https://www.mapmyindia.com/api/advanced-maps/doc/autosuggest-api). I tried referring to the example provided in the source code but the source code is written in PHP and I'm using javascript to build the app. Also, I don't know PHP. It would be great if someone can suggest a way to use the API.

Comment: Did you get any solution for javascript?

Comment: I dropped the project. They have been making a few updates lately. Please check their GitHub repo https://github.com/MapmyIndia

Answer (score 0):

```
$token_url = "https://outpost.mappls.com/api/security/oauth/token";
$access_token = "";
$token_type = "";
$data = get_safe_value($_POST['val']);
$datac = [
    "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
    "client_id" => "Your Client Id Here",
    "client_secret" => "Your Client Secret Here",
];
$str = http_build_query($datac);
$curl_token = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_token, CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
curl_setopt($curl_token, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_token, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_token, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);
curl_setopt($curl_token, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_token, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_token, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result_token = curl_exec($curl_token);
curl_close($curl_token);
$start = strpos($result_token, '{');
$end = strrpos($result_token, '}');

if ($start !== false && $end !== false) {
    $jsonString = substr($result_token, $start, $end - $start + 1);
    $jsonData = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        $output = 0;
        $access_token = $jsonData['access_token'];
        $token_type = $jsonData['token_type'];
    } else {
        $arr = "Error decoding JSON: " . json_last_error_msg();
        $output = 1;
    }
} else {
    $output = 2;
    $arr = "JSON not found in the string.";
}
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$header[] = 'Authorization: ' . $token_type . ' ' . $access_token . '';
$url = "https://atlas.mappls.com/api/places/search/json?query=" . $data . "";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
// $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
// also get the error and response code
// $errors = curl_error($curl);
//echo $errors;
// $output = $result_token;
$arr[5] = $result;
```

These $arr are for testing the output

It worked for me , you can try it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).